# Get Entity Types by calling Dynamics 365 API

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016

Can I found out what entity types are available by calling Dynamics 365 API?

Practically I want this list.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/da-dk/library/mt593046.aspx#bkmk_DerivedEntityTypes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get entity list using Web API. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607833.aspx) is description of it. For example you will get all LogicalNames from this:

```
http://[SERVER_NAME]/[ORG_NAME]/api/data/v8.1/EntityDefinitions?$select=LogicalName
```

Comment: Do you know how can I get the possibile Actions list?